# How to assign a value in SQL based on Date Condition

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table in which I need to update the tolerance value for an order. The tolerance value is based on a retailer. There can be multiple tolerance values that apply for a given timeframe. I need to be able to update the tolerance value for orders that were created in the tolerance timeframe.

For example I have the following tolerance details:

| cust_id | cust_name | early_tolerance | late_tolerance | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 15 | 2 | 1/1/2001 | 4/17/2023 |
| 1 | ABC | 2 | 1 | 4/18/2023 | NULL |
| 5 | EEE | 6 | 2 | 2/18/2020 | NULL |
| 9 | JD | 5 | 5 | 6/18/2021 | NULL |

Table 2 that I am joining to:

| order_no | order_create_date | cust_id | cust_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 2020-09-18 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC |
| 21 | 2021-10-30 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC |
| 33 | 2023-03-23 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC |
| 26 | 2022-09-12 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC |
| 15 | 2023-04-18 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC |
| 40 | 2023-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC |
| 130 | 2023-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 5 | EEE |
| 407 | 2023-04-02 00:00:00.000 | 9 | JD |
| 409 | 2022-01-20 00:00:00.000 | 9 | JD |
| 320 | 2020-05-28 00:00:00.000 | 5 | EEE |

Need the following output:

| order_no | order_create_date | cust_id | cust_name | early_tolerance | late_tolerance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 2020-09-18 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC | 15 | 2 |
| 21 | 2021-10-30 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC | 15 | 2 |
| 33 | 2023-03-23 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC | 15 | 2 |
| 26 | 2022-09-12 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC | 15 | 2 |
| 15 | 2023-04-18 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC | 2 | 1 |
| 40 | 2023-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 1 | ABC | 2 | 1 |
| 130 | 2023-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 5 | EEE | 6 | 2 |
| 407 | 2023-04-02 00:00:00.000 | 9 | JD | 5 | 5 |
| 409 | 2022-01-20 00:00:00.000 | 9 | JD | 5 | 5 |
| 320 | 2020-05-28 00:00:00.000 | 5 | EEE | 6 | 2 |

The tolerance value is according to order_create_date that falls in the start_date and end_date range for the tolerance table. So for the given example, all orders older than or equal to 4/17/2023 should have the old tolerance value of 15, 1 while orders after that will have 2,1. There can be scenarios where we can have more than 2 different tolerance entries.

```
select order_no, order_create_date, cust_no, cust_name,
       case when order_create_date between start_date and end_date
            then early_tolerance
       end as early_tolerance,
       case when order_create_date between start_date and end_date
            then late_tolerance
       end as late_tolerance
from table1
  left join table2 on table1.cust_no = table2.cust_no
```

I don't think this will work as I need to account for the NULL end dates as well. Please advise on how best to tackle this issue. Thanks.

Update: The logic below creates a row for each tolerance value. What I need is for the first row to have a tolerance of 2 and 1 since the order create date is equal to start date for that tolerance. Order #21 should have a tolerance of 15 and 2.
[image: Online Example]

Comment: Wherever you use `end_date` substitute with `coalesce(end_date, date '9999-12-31')`

Comment: Thanks, @tinazmu - I considered putting in a coalesce but don't want to have to create a hypothetical end date. The bigger issue that I need help with is how to apply the tolerance for orders that fall in specific date range.

Comment: I don't understand. What @tinazmu proposed in his answer defintely works as you can see in [this demo dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rQChpxk-). Logic is correct, output is exactly as you wanted.

Comment: This is also an industry-standard solution to this type of problem, though in many cases the “dummy” end date would be physically held in the table specifically to avoid this type of problem